# Angular: function inside *ngIf causes performance issues but what is the alternative?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

So I have an issue with performance and figured out throughsearching the web that it's caused by all the functions that I have inside *ngIf's. Some recommedations are to use pipes or to use get accessors. I tried pipes and it does not work and I can't use get accessors as the functions havet parameters.

some functions are simple and others more complex. The state can be changed by the user by adding or deleting things from arrays so it has to stay dynamic. example function

```
function inBothArrays(id, array1, array2) {
    if(array1.includes(id) && array2.includes(id)){
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should probably have the arrays defined somewhere in the component, rather than passing them every time. this should not be such big performance hit though, unless the arrays are huge. also, the code can be simplified like this:
return (array1.includes(id) && array2.includes(id))

Comment: Thanks and I do have the arrays defined in the component.  The component is recursive though and on a hover this function will be called 100's of times for no reason and will cause the application to freeze.

Comment: Why is it recursive, and why is it called 100's of times on hover? makes sense that is not very performant if you're also passing the arrays every time. can you show how that is implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would i do is create a pipe for the job.
As stated in Angular documentation

> Angular executes a pure pipe only when it detects a pure change to the input value. A pure change is either a change to a primitive input value (String, Number, Boolean, Symbol) or a changed object reference (Date, Array, Function, Object).

So what you probably need is to create a "inBothArraysPipe" that takes as input both the arrays and the item to check as a single object who's reference changes only when you decide to change it. 
You would then modify your code like this:

1) turn your *ngIf in something like

```
*ngIf=" checkDto | inBothArrays "
```

2) define checkDto in your component as

```
checkDto : {id: any, array1: any[], array2 : any[]}
```

3) be sure to change the reference of checkDto every time you:

- modify array1
- modify array2
- modify the id

To change the reference you can throw in a

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(checkDto))
```

or

```
Object.assign({}, checkDto)
```